# Adding a Button that Sends an Email in an Email

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

So I have customers that go to my site and request quotes for moving their cars. I get this form emailed to me and then I reply in an email with their quote. In this email I ask them to reply saying that they are ready to move their cars so that I can begin working on setting up their move.

However I feel I can make this step more streamlined. I'd like to have a button in my email that just says something like "Click here if you are ready to move your car!" Is this possible?

I would need this button to let me know which customer it is. I have a unique ID for every job and I could manually configure it before I send the email with the quote. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you want that you click on that button and a mail will fire with that customer ??

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is with URL parameters. Something like:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/confirm.php?account=customer@email.com&confirm=true">Click Here to Confirm</a>
```

That could be an image/button if you prefer. You would then use `$_GET('account')` on your page to access the query/parameter values.

You would have to dynamically insert the custome values before you send the email, as you can't change any of the code once it is sent. There are plenty of transactional email services that can help streamline this for you, all of which are designed to integrate with API's. A couple of good ones that come to mind are SendGrid, Mandrill and Mailjet.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do would be to insert a link to a page on your website passing the unique ID as a query string. Then your page can display some sort of confirmation message to the customer and send you a message saying that the customer is ready.